# Angular ngmock httpBackend - ignore all but one request?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, xmlhttprequest, httpbackend

I am new to writing unit tests, so apologies if this is a dumb question. If I'm trying to test a method in an Angular controller that relies on mock data from a service call, and I want to also mock that service call (ngResource), is there a way to make httpBackend ignore other requests made in my controller on initialization?

I've tried placing my whenGET or expectGET definitions in before blocks, and only instantiating my controller within my test, but I always find that httpBackend is expecting other requests (Error: Unexpected request) when I call flush(). I do not want to write mocks for all other requests, just the one I'm using for this test.

Of course, this may be a stupid idea, as I can also just provide the fake data directly, and not test the service along with the controller's method. I've verified that this works. Maybe the correct answer is that I shouldn't be testing services from within a controller.

FWIW, I've also tried using Sinon fakeServer, and apparently it doesn't even pick up on Angular's XHR implementation (the server never responds).